# how can i read a custom DataSource(*.json) by Cesium

Tags: json, cesiumjs

i have a grb2 file, i use grib2json covert it to .json, here is the json code:

```
[
{
    "header":{
        "discipline":0,
        "disciplineName":"Meteorological products",
        "gribEdition":2,
        "gribLength":455039,
        "center":7,
        "centerName":"US National Weather Service - NCEP(WMC)",
        "subcenter":0,
        "refTime":"2016-10-05T12:00:00.000Z",
        "significanceOfRT":1,
        "significanceOfRTName":"Start of forecast",
        "productStatus":0,
        "productStatusName":"Operational products",
        "productType":1,
        "productTypeName":"Forecast products",
        "productDefinitionTemplate":0,
        "productDefinitionTemplateName":"Analysis/forecast at horizontal level/layer at a point in time",
        "parameterCategory":2,
        "parameterCategoryName":"Momentum",
        "parameterNumber":3,
        "parameterNumberName":"V-component_of_wind",
        "parameterUnit":"m.s-1",
        "genProcessType":2,
        "genProcessTypeName":"Forecast",
        "forecastTime":0,
        "surface1Type":103,
        "surface1TypeName":"Specified height level above ground",
        "surface1Value":10.0,
        "surface2Type":255,
        "surface2TypeName":"Missing",
        "surface2Value":0.0,
        "gridDefinitionTemplate":0,
        "gridDefinitionTemplateName":"Latitude_Longitude",
        "numberPoints":259920,
        "shape":6,
        "shapeName":"Earth spherical with radius of 6,371,229.0 m",
        "gridUnits":"degrees",
        "resolution":48,
        "winds":"true",
        "scanMode":0,
        "nx":720,
        "ny":361,
        "basicAngle":0,
        "subDivisions":0,
        "lo1":0.0,
        "la1":90.0,
        "lo2":359.5,
        "la2":-90.0,
        "dx":0.5,
        "dy":0.5
    },
    "data":[
        3.92,
        3.89,
        ......
        -3.06,
        -3.07
    ]
}
```

]

when i use Cesium1.26 to read the json file, it works, but i can't get the header and data, can anyone help me about this problem?

Comment: Can you post a more complete example?  Also are you trying to get Cesium to display some of this data, or just trying to access the data from within your app after Cesium loads it?

Comment: now i can load data from file by use Cesium and JQuery , i want to display the temp data or the wind data by use Cesium.

Comment: i want to covert data to a WebGLGlobeDataSource, but i don't know how WebGLGlobeDataSource works...